# Query Wrong Results After change for better performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, group-by, query-optimization

I had a query which was taking too long to return the results but I tried to change it and group the results on the basis of ID but it is now returning more results than before it may be due to duplicated results are returned.

Here is the old Query:

```
(from p in se.CompanyRepresentatives
                    let internshipApplication = (from q in p.QuestionnaireResponses
                                                 where q.QuestionnaireID == SurveyEntities.STUDENT_INTERNSHIP_PROFILE
                                                 select q).FirstOrDefault()
                    let pendingApplications = (from q in p.InternshipMatches
                                               where InterneeViewModel.PENDING_INTRO_MATCH_STATUSES.Contains(q.Status)
                                               select q).Count()

                    let rejectedApplications = (from q in p.InternshipMatches
                                                where InterneeViewModel.REJECTED_INTRO_STATUSES.Contains(q.Status) &&

                                                //Only current year's internships
                                                DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Internship.Created).Value, yearStart) > 0 &&
                                                DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Internship.Created).Value, yearEnd) < 0

                                                select q).Count()
                    where
                        //Only current year's internship applications
                        DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(internshipApplication.Updated).Value, yearStart) > 0 &&
                        DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(internshipApplication.Updated).Value, yearEnd) < 0 &&
                        interneeIds.Contains(p.ID) && internshipApplication != null
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        University = p.TamidChapter.Name,
                        MatchStatus = p.RespondentStatus,
                        Rank = p.Rank,
                        Posted = internshipApplication.Updated,
                        Visible = !p.IsHidden,
                        lang = p.Languages,
                        grad = p.Graduation,
                        major = p.Majors,
                        pendingApplications,
                        rejectedApplications,
                        industry_1 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_1).Answer,
                        industry_2 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_2).Answer,
                        industry_3 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_3).Answer,
                        industryOther = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_OTHER).Select(x=>x.Answer),
                        industryEss = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRIES_REASON).Answer,
                        preferredCompanyType = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == COMPANY_TYPE).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        jobDes_1 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_1).Answer,
                        jobDes_2 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_2).Answer,
                        jobDes_3 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_3).Answer,
                        jobDesOther = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_OTHER).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        market = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == INTERESTED_MARKETS).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        marketReason = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INTERESTED_MARKETS_REASON).Answer,
                        codelang = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == CODING_LANGUAGES).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        CONSULTING_FINANCE_VC = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == CONSULTING_FINANCE_VC).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        officeSize = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == OFFICE_SIZE).Answer,
                        preferredType = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == EXPECTED_EXPERIENCE).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        hourComute = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == WILL_COMMUTE).Answer,
                        cityPlacement = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == LOCATION).Answer,
                        workHours = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == WORK_DAY).Answer,
                        specCompany = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == SPEC_COMPANY).Answer,
                        consultingCompany = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INTERNSHIP_WITH_CONSULTING_COMPANY).AnswerCode

                    }).ToList().Select(p =>
                    new InterneeViewModel
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        University = p.University,
                        Status = (IndividualStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(IndividualStatus), p.MatchStatus),
                        Rank = p.Rank,
                        Posted = p.Posted,
                        Visible = p.Visible,
                        Languages = p.lang,
                        Graduation = p.grad.ToString(),
                        Majors = p.major,
                        PendingMatches = p.pendingApplications,
                        NoOfRejectedApplication = p.rejectedApplications,
                        Industry1 = p.industry_1,
                        Industry2 = p.industry_2,
                        Industry3 = p.industry_3,
                        IndustryOther = p.industryOther.ToList(),
                        IndustriesReason = p.industryEss,
                        CompanyTypes = p.preferredCompanyType.ToList(),
                        JobDesc1 = p.jobDes_1,
                        JobDesc2 = p.jobDes_2,
                        JobDesc3 = p.jobDes_3,
                        JobDescOther = p.jobDesOther.ToList(),
                        InterestedMarkets = p.market.ToList(),
                        InterestedMarketsReason = p.marketReason,
                        CodingLanguages = p.codelang.ToList(),
                        ConsultingFinanceVC = p.CONSULTING_FINANCE_VC.ToList(),
                        OfficeSize = p.officeSize,
                        TypesOfExperience = p.preferredType.ToList(),
                        IsCommuter = p.hourComute,
                        Location = p.cityPlacement,
                        WorkDay = p.workHours,
                        SpecCompany = p.specCompany,
                        InternshipWithConsultingCompany = "Yes".Equals(p.consultingCompany, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
}).ToList();
```

As you may see it is querying repeatedly for getting different results in select statement. I grouped the responses on the basis of questionID then I query that grouped list for different results but it is returning more results than before it looks like I am doing something wrong.

Here is the new Query grouped Responses by QuestionID:

```
(from p in se.CompanyRepresentatives
                    
                    from questionRes in p.Responses.GroupBy(x => x.QuestionID)
                    let internshipApplication = (from q in p.QuestionnaireResponses
                                                 where q.QuestionnaireID == SurveyEntities.STUDENT_INTERNSHIP_PROFILE
                                                 select q).FirstOrDefault()
                    let pendingApplications = (from q in p.InternshipMatches
                                               where InterneeViewModel.PENDING_INTRO_MATCH_STATUSES.Contains(q.Status)
                                               select q).Count()

                    let rejectedApplications = (from q in p.InternshipMatches
                                                where InterneeViewModel.REJECTED_INTRO_STATUSES.Contains(q.Status) &&

                                                //Only current year's internships
                                                DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Internship.Created).Value, yearStart) > 0 &&
                                                DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(q.Internship.Created).Value, yearEnd) < 0

                                                select q).Count()
                    where
                        //Only current year's internship applications
                        DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(internshipApplication.Updated).Value, yearStart) > 0 &&
                        DateTime.Compare(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(internshipApplication.Updated).Value, yearEnd) < 0 &&
                        interneeIds.Contains(p.ID) && internshipApplication != null
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        University = p.TamidChapter.Name,
                        MatchStatus = p.RespondentStatus,
                        Rank = p.Rank,
                        Posted = internshipApplication.Updated,
                        Visible = !p.IsHidden,
                        lang = p.Languages,
                        grad = p.Graduation,
                        major = p.Majors,
                        pendingApplications,
                        rejectedApplications,
                        industry_1 = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_1).Answer,
                        industry_2 = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_2).Answer,
                        industry_3 = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_3).Answer,
                        industryOther = questionRes.Where(y => y.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_OTHER).Select(x=>x.Answer),
                        industryEss = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRIES_REASON).Answer,
                        preferredCompanyType = questionRes.Where(y => y.QuestionID == COMPANY_TYPE).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        jobDes_1 = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_1).Answer,
                        jobDes_2 = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_2).Answer,
                        jobDes_3 = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_3).Answer,
                        jobDesOther = questionRes.Where(y => y.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_OTHER).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        market = questionRes.Where(y => y.QuestionID == INTERESTED_MARKETS).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        marketReason = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INTERESTED_MARKETS_REASON).Answer,
                        codelang = questionRes.Where(y => y.QuestionID == CODING_LANGUAGES).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        CONSULTING_FINANCE_VC = questionRes.Where(y => y.QuestionID == CONSULTING_FINANCE_VC).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        officeSize = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == OFFICE_SIZE).Answer,
                        preferredType = questionRes.Where(y => y.QuestionID == EXPECTED_EXPERIENCE).Select(x => x.Answer),
                        hourComute = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == WILL_COMMUTE).Answer,
                        cityPlacement = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == LOCATION).Answer,
                        workHours = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == WORK_DAY).Answer,
                        specCompany = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == SPEC_COMPANY).Answer,
                        consultingCompany = questionRes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INTERNSHIP_WITH_CONSULTING_COMPANY).AnswerCode

                    }).ToList().Select(p =>
                    new InterneeViewModel
                    {
                        ID = p.ID,
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Email = p.Email,
                        University = p.University,
                        Status = (IndividualStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(IndividualStatus), p.MatchStatus),
                        Rank = p.Rank,
                        Posted = p.Posted,
                        Visible = p.Visible,
                        Languages = p.lang,
                        Graduation = p.grad.ToString(),
                        Majors = p.major,
                        PendingMatches = p.pendingApplications,
                        NoOfRejectedApplication = p.rejectedApplications,
                        Industry1 = p.industry_1,
                        Industry2 = p.industry_2,
                        Industry3 = p.industry_3,
                        IndustryOther = p.industryOther.ToList(),
                        IndustriesReason = p.industryEss,
                        CompanyTypes = p.preferredCompanyType.ToList(),
                        JobDesc1 = p.jobDes_1,
                        JobDesc2 = p.jobDes_2,
                        JobDesc3 = p.jobDes_3,
                        JobDescOther = p.jobDesOther.ToList(),
                        InterestedMarkets = p.market.ToList(),
                        InterestedMarketsReason = p.marketReason,
                        CodingLanguages = p.codelang.ToList(),
                        ConsultingFinanceVC = p.CONSULTING_FINANCE_VC.ToList(),
                        OfficeSize = p.officeSize,
                        TypesOfExperience = p.preferredType.ToList(),
                        IsCommuter = p.hourComute,
                        Location = p.cityPlacement,
                        WorkDay = p.workHours,
                        SpecCompany = p.specCompany,
                        InternshipWithConsultingCompany = "Yes".Equals(p.consultingCompany, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Show generated SQL for old variant. And which EF version do you use?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am using EF 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query. Main idea to load responses and process them on the client side. Also change way how to work with dates, `TruncateTime` disables indexes, if they exists for sure.

```cs
var yearStart = ...
var yearEnd = yearStart.AddYears(1);

var rawQuery =
    from p in se.CompanyRepresentatives
    from internshipApplication in p.QuestionnaireResponses
        .Where(q => q.QuestionnaireID == SurveyEntities.STUDENT_INTERNSHIP_PROFILE)
        .Take(1)
    let pendingApplications = (from q in p.InternshipMatches
                            where InterneeViewModel.PENDING_INTRO_MATCH_STATUSES.Contains(q.Status)
                            select q).Count()

    let rejectedApplications = (from q in p.InternshipMatches
                                where InterneeViewModel.REJECTED_INTRO_STATUSES.Contains(q.Status) &&

                                //Only current year's internships
                                q.Internship.Created.Value >= yearStart &&
                                q.Internship.Created.Value < yearEnd
                                select q).Count()
    where
        //Only current year's internship applications
        internshipApplication.Updated.Value >= yearStart &&
        internshipApplication.Updated.Value < yearEnd &&
        interneeIds.Contains(p.ID)
    select new
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
        Email = p.Email,
        University = p.TamidChapter.Name,
        MatchStatus = p.RespondentStatus,
        Rank = p.Rank,
        Posted = internshipApplication.Updated,
        Visible = !p.IsHidden,
        lang = p.Languages,
        grad = p.Graduation,
        major = p.Majors,
        pendingApplications,
        rejectedApplications,
        Responses = p.Responses.Select(r => new { r.Answer, r.AnswerCode, r.QuestionID }).ToList()
    };

var result = rawQuery
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => new InterneeViewModel
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        Name = p.Name,
        Email = p.Email,
        University = p.University,
        Status = (IndividualStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(IndividualStatus), p.MatchStatus),
        Rank = p.Rank,
        Posted = p.Posted,
        Visible = p.Visible,
        Languages = p.lang,
        Graduation = p.grad.ToString(),
        Majors = p.major,
        PendingMatches = p.pendingApplications,
        NoOfRejectedApplication = p.rejectedApplications,

        Industry1 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_1)?.Answer,
        Industry2 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_2)?.Answer,
        Industry3 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_3)?.Answer,
        IndustryOther = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == INDUSTRY_OTHER).Select(x=> x.Answer).ToList(),
        IndustriesReason = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INDUSTRIES_REASON)?.Answer,
        CompanyTypes = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == COMPANY_TYPE).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        JobDesc1 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_1)?.Answer,
        JobDesc2 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_2)?.Answer,
        JobDesc3 = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_3)?.Answer,
        JobDescOther = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == JOB_DESCRIPTION_OTHER).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        InterestedMarkets = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == INTERESTED_MARKETS).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        InterestedMarketsReason = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INTERESTED_MARKETS_REASON)?.Answer,
        CodingLanguages = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == CODING_LANGUAGES).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        ConsultingFinanceVC = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == CONSULTING_FINANCE_VC).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        OfficeSize = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == OFFICE_SIZE)?.Answer,
        TypesOfExperience = p.Responses.Where(y => y.QuestionID == EXPECTED_EXPERIENCE).Select(x => x.Answer).ToList(),
        IsCommuter = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == WILL_COMMUTE)?.Answer,
        Location = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == LOCATION)?.Answer,
        WorkDay = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == WORK_DAY)?.Answer,
        SpecCompany = p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == SPEC_COMPANY)?.Answer,
        InternshipWithConsultingCompany = "Yes".Equals(p.Responses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QuestionID == INTERNSHIP_WITH_CONSULTING_COMPANY)?.AnswerCode, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this still was taking time then I used this line and it reduced from 40 sec to 7 sec
Responses = p.Responses.Where(x=> questionIds.Contains(x.QuestionID)).ToList()

Comment: Yes, it should reduce amount of records. I just don't know nature of your data. Splitting queries may increase speed also but it needs another algorithm.

Comment: Can you please help me to make this query more better?

Comment: Have you tried `AsSplitQuery()` for `rawQuery`?